# Puppeteer returns an innerText value in uppercase because of CSS

Tags: puppeteer

Using the proper selector, the evaluate function and the innerText property, I'm trying to extract the content of a div such as:

```
<div class="abc">Interesting stuff</div>
```

But the css class transforms the content into uppercase : INTERESTING STUFF

Is it normal that the innerText property returns the uppercase rather than the "original" text? Is there a way to get this "original" text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with the following properties:

- `innerHTML` parses content as HTML, so it takes longer.
- `textContent` uses straight text, does not parse HTML, and is faster.

Examples:

**innerHTML:**

```
const text = await page.$eval('.abc', elem => elem.innerHTML); // returns 'Interesting stuff'
```

**textContent:**

```
const text = await page.$eval('.abc', elem => elem.textContent); // returns 'Interesting stuff'
```

From API [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML):

> The `innerHTML` returns HTML or XML fragment is generated based on the current
>   contents of the element, so the markup and formatting of the returned
>   fragment is likely not to match the original page markup.
>
> The `textContent` returns every element in the node. In contrast, innerText is aware of styling and won’t return the text of “hidden” elements. Moreover, since innerText takes CSS styles into account, reading the value of innerText triggers a reflow to ensure up-to-date computed styles. (Reflows can be computationally expensive, and thus should be avoided when possible.)

Comment: Since it's faster, I tried the textContent property and it works perfectly. Thank you for your quick and thorough answer.

Comment: Happy to help!(: